# Expo Router Navigation problem after first navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have an Expo app and there are `profile` and `profile/[id]` routes. When app is opened, i can navigate one of them but after that, there is a problem with navigation.

When i tried to navigate again one of these routes, it is not working and there no error.

`(tabs)/_layout.jsx`

```
   <Tabs
      initialRouteName="index"
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="post"
        options={{
          unmountOnBlur: true,
        }}
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="profile"
        listeners={() => ({
          tabPress: (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigation.navigate("profile", {
              screen: "index",
              initial: false,
            });
          },
        })}
      />
      
    </Tabs>
```

`(tabs)/profile/_layout.jsx`

```
 <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        contentStyle: {
          backgroundColor: themeColors.backgroundColor,
        },
      }}
      initialRouteName="index"
    />
```

```
  <Link
        href={
          user?.id === userId
            ? {
                pathname: "/profile",
              }
            : {
                pathname: "/profile/[id]",
                params: { id: userId },
              }
        }
        asChild
      >
```

[AppStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MXSV.png)

I tried to navigate with useNavigation, useRouter and set unMountOnBlur to true. Then i find it is a problem with navigation to already mounted for once page